# Why do electrons and holes in the base have to recombine in order to create the base current

Tags: transistors, semiconductors

[Khan academy link](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/in-in-class-12th-physics-india/in-in-semiconductors/in-in-transistors/v/transistor-working-class-12-india-physics-khan-academy)

In the video above, it is said, that in order for the base current to appear, electrons have to recombine with the holes in the base region.

Why can't they simply go to the base electrode directly?

Is it somehow related to the semiconductor-metal junction as in Shottky diode?

Comment: This has been answered so many times here. The base is very thin. As charges accelerate from the emitter towards the base across the junction, most of them fail to recombine in the base because it's so thin. Instead, they mostly wind up in the collector where they can move at their mean free velocity to be collected at the collector lead. Some of them do recombine in the base and must be removed by the base lead in order to reestablish the equilibrium state of the BJT's base region.

Comment: But still one has lot of electrons in the base. Is it that there is a barrier (thinner that at a PN junction) at the base-lead junction that prevents minority carriers (electrons in NPN, AFAIK) from going to the lead directly?

Comment: I think I understand why you ask your question. The root cause is the two phases (1) "Why they have to combine", (2) "in order to create". I would see it this way. (a) They combine because it is "natural" for they to combine, not because there is another reason. (b) Now if they combine, (i) electrons can now come out from the base terminal to the positive biased voltage source, / to continue, ...

Comment: (ii) and the condition that "what goes in must come out (Kirchhoff's 1st Law) is satisfied: (a) The small quantity of electrons goes into E, combining with holes, and comes out at B, this is the small loop. (b) The big loop is another large quantity of electrons also goes into E, but comes (without combination with holes) out at C. So, small and big quantity of electrons go into the transistor = small and large quantity of electrons come out of the transistor. I know I am long winded, but I need to repeat and be redundant a bit, and I find it difficult to shorten my explanation.

Comment: I know there is a "loop hole" in my explanation: If those small quantity of electrons don't combine in the base, no same small quantity of electrons (quantity only, not the "same electrons who got married and stuck in the base) cannot come out at the base.

Comment: As a general rule, Martin, I IMHO find Khan's videos rather low quality (ofc there're exceptions) for teaching. Unfortunately, these semiconductor physics concepts are not very easy to graps and applying them to a wider concept e.g. BJTs makes everything tougher. A textbook is widely better and there many free ones on the web ([one](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/welcome.htm), [two](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~hu/Book-Chapters-and-Lecture-Slides-download.html)).

Comment: Thanks edmz, I'll look at these. And thank you guys for your explanations.